# I want to filter a listview item from any position

Tags: java, android, listview, listview-filter

I want to filter a listView in such a way that when user types a word/string in the editText which occurs in the listView item...that item should be filtered....In the below code the search starts from the initial character of the item....For Eg:items:sachin,dhoni,yuvraj.....if i search for v....the search filter should show me yuvraj...

here's my code:

```
package com.example.acer.aartisangrah;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class first extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
private ListView listView;

private String[] names = {"प्रार्थना",
        "सुखकर्ता दु:खहर्ता",
        "गजानना श्रीगणराया",
        "येई हो विठ्ठले",
        "लवथवती विक्राळा",
        "दुर्गे दुर्घट भारी",
        "आरती ज्ञानराजा",
        "हे भोळ्या शंकरा",
        "ओवाळू आरती",
        "मंगेशा महारूद्रा",
        "आला गणराया",
        "शेंदुर लाल चढायो",
        "एकदंता",
        "कर्पूर गौरा",
        "हे गजवधना",
        "प्रथमेश्वरा",
        "जयदेवा हे  साईनाथा",
        "श्री सत्यनारायणाची आरती",
        "श्री महालक्ष्मीची आरती",
        "ॐ जय लक्ष्मी माता",
        "आरती संतोषी माता की",
        "धन्य धन्य हो प्रदक्षिणा",
        "सुखंकर्ता की दु:खहर्ता",
        "ॐ जय जगदीश",
        "जय श्री विश्वकर्मा",
        "हे गौरी गजानन",
        "घालीन लोटांगण"};
private int imageid[] = {R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganpati,
        R.drawable.vittal,
        R.drawable.shivji,
        R.drawable.durgamaa,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.shivji,
        R.drawable.krishna,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.saibaba,
        R.drawable.satyanarayanadev,
        R.drawable.laxmimaa,
        R.drawable.laxmimaa,
        R.drawable.santoshimaa,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganpati,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji};
int textlength = 0;
ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(names, imageid));
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()

    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textlength = editText.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= names[i].length()) {
                    if (editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)names[i].subSequence(0,textlength))) {
                        text_sort.add(names[i]);
                        image_sort.add(imageid[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));
        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            String strSelectedString = tv.getText().toString();
            for (int selectedPosition = 0; selectedPosition < names.length; selectedPosition++) {
                if (names[selectedPosition].equalsIgnoreCase(strSelectedString)) {
                    moveToNextActivity(selectedPosition);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    });
}

public void moveToNextActivity(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), akalp.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 1) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sukharta.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 2) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gajananashriganraya.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 3) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yehihovittale.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 4) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), lavathavthi.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 5) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), durgedurgat.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 6) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nyanraja.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 7) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bolya.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 8) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vovalo.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 9) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mangesha.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 10) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), alaganraya.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 11) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), shendorlal.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 12) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ekdanta.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 13) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), karpurgaura.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 14) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), heygajavadana.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 15) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prathmeshvara.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 16) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sainatha.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 17) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), satyanarayan.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 18) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), jaidevijaidevi.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 19) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), omjaimahalakshmi.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 20) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), maitohaarti.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 21) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), danyadanyaho.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 22) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sukhartakidukharta.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 23) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), omjaijagdish.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 24) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vishwakarma.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 25) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), heygaurigajanana.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
    if (position == 26) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ghalinlotangan.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.action_about){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aboutusActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(editText.getText().toString().length()>0){
        editText.setText("");
        listView.setSelection(0);}
        else
        finish();
}

class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] data_text;
    int[] data_image;

    MyCustomAdapter() {

    }

    MyCustomAdapter(String[] names, int[] imageid) {
        data_text = names;
        data_image = imageid;
    }

    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> imageid) {
        data_text = new String[names.size()];
        data_image = new int[imageid.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            data_text[i] = names.get(i);
            data_image[i] = imageid.get(i);
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data_text.length;
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textview.setText(data_text[position]);
        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);
        return (row);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your ***adapter class***

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            searchlocation.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0)
            {
                searchlocation.addAll(arraylist);
            }
            else
            {
                for (SearchLocation wp : arraylist)
                {
                    if (wp.getLocation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) || wp.getcity().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) )
                    {

                        searchlocation.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }}
```

---

Add this in your ***Activity class***

```
editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);


            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });
```

Comment: cant i just do it by changing this line:  if (editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)names[i].subSequence(0,textlength)))

Comment: i tried the above code before but i dont know exactly what to do with it....And I'm new to developing

Comment: wait i explain it to you

Comment: you want to search in which array list ? this is the one **ArrayList<String> names**

Comment: Ya....the text in the editText(search bar) should match any character from listView item....

Comment: @Devk did you try my adapter?

Comment: @pskink i dint understand your code...plus i dont know where to put oyur code...if you can help me i can give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the items and test if they contain the search text.

```
ArrayList <string> strList = new ArrayList<string> ();
String search = "h";
For each string in dataList
    If string.contains (search)
        strList.add (string);
```